# Solr facet equivalent of group by?

Tags: sorting, solr

If I have some data like this:

```
{"field1":"x", "field2":".."}
{"field1":"x", "field2":".."}
{"field1":"y", "field2":".."}
{"field1":"y", "field2":".."}
{"field1":"y", "field2":".."}
```

Using a simple `group=true&group.field=field1&group.limit=0` I get results like this:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{..}
  "grouped":{
        "field1": {
            "matches": 5,
            "groups": [

                {"groupValue": "x", "doclist":{"numFound": 2, ...}}
                {"groupValue": "y", "doclist":{"numFound": 3, ...}}

            ]
        }

  }
}
```

Using this, I know the num of documents found for each `groupValue` (`numFound`). The problem is I need to sort the resulting groups in descending order, which is not possible with either sort (a simple `sort=numFound` would result in an exception, saying the field `numFound` does not exists and the group.sort would sort the documents inside each group).

Is there an equivalent of this using facets where I can sort the results by count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/your_core/select?facet.field=field1&facet.sort=count&facet.limit=-1&facet=on&indent=on&q=*:*&rows=0&start=0&wt=json
```

The result will be something like:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":17,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "facet.field":"field1",
      "indent":"on",
      "start":"0",
      "rows":"0",
      "facet":"on",
      "wt":"json"}},
  "response":{"numFound":225364,"start":0,"docs":[]
  },
  "facet_counts":{
    "facet_queries":{},
    "facet_fields":{
      "field1":[
        "x",113550,
        "y",111814]},
    "facet_ranges":{},
    "facet_intervals":{},
    "facet_heatmaps":{}
  }
}
```

Just tested with Solr 6.3.0.

For more information you can check related part in the [Solr documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/faceting.html#Faceting-Thefacet.sortParameter).

If you want to compute simultaneously the number of available facets, you can use Solr `stats` Component (as the field is of type numeric, string, or date).
Have in mind though, server performance and memory overhead issues might appear.

Running a query like:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/your_core/select?facet.field=field1&facet.sort=count&facet.limit=10&facet=true&indent=on&q=*:*&rows=0&start=0&wt=json&stats=true&stats.field={!cardinality=true}field1
```

The response is something like:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":614,
    "params":{
      "facet.limit":"10",
      "q":"*:*",
      "facet.field":"field1",
      "indent":"on",
      "stats":"true",
      "start":"0",
      "rows":"0",
      "facet":"true",
      "wt":"json",
      "facet.sort":"count",
      "stats.field":"{!cardinality=true}field1"}},
  "response":{"numFound":2336315,"start":0,"docs":[]
  },
  "facet_counts":{
    "facet_queries":{},
    "facet_fields":{
      "field1":[
        "Value1",708116,
        "Value2",607088,
        "Value3",493949,
        "Value4",314433,
        "Value5",104478,
        "Value6",41099,
        "Value7",28879,
        "Value8",18767,
        "Value9",9308,
        "Value10",4545]},
    "facet_ranges":{},
    "facet_intervals":{},
    "facet_heatmaps":{}},
  "stats":{
    "stats_fields":{
      "field1":{
        "cardinality":27}}}}
```

For more information about `stats` you can check [here](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-stats-component.html).

Comment: I tried it too, also, I did not mention it beforehand, but I actually have quite large number of results. I could page through the results with `facet.offset` and `facet.limit`, but Solr just won't print the count of groups (like the grouping does). Do you know any way to get a total count (of facet result)?

Comment: You want to get all facets (groups) in one query with relevant counts? If so, you could use facet.limit=-1. If you want total count of the results, can't you just use `numFound` property of `response`?

Comment: @Izagkaretos Unfortunately, I need to create a pageable table from the results. The numFound indicates the number of documents found, not the number of groups created after the field merging.

Comment: Ok, the required information missing in faceted approach is the total count of facets?

Comment: Yes, I need to know the number of facets to tell which page is the last one, or else I only know the current page, I wouldn't even know If there is a next page, only after querying it.

Comment: May I ask what type is the field you want to use as a group (facet) key?

Comment: @Izagkaretos `string`, dynamic mapped `name="*_s" type="string"`